# Product Variation for and Ecommerce App using Angular 9

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular9

Good day,
I'm still a newbie in Angular and I've been trying to create a product variation in an Angular 9 E-commerce app I'm building.
i want it to be set that if i click a product variation button, the product price will change.
There are seven product variation
Below is my html code

```
            <button class="naomi" (click)="priceChange1($event)" *ngIf = "product.price1">{{product.three}}</button>
            <button class="naomi" (click)="priceChange2($event)" *ngIf = " product.price2">{{product.four}}</button>
            <button class="naomi" (click)="priceChange3($event)" *ngIf = "product.price3">{{product.five}}</button>
            <button class="naomi" (click)="priceChange4($event)" *ngIf = "product.price4">{{product.six}}</button>
            <button class="naomi" (click)="priceChange5($event)" *ngIf = "product.price5">{{product.seven}}</button>
            <button class="naomi" (click)="priceChange6($event)" *ngIf = "product.price6">{{product.seventy}}</button>
            <button class="naomi" (click)="priceChange7($event)" *ngIf = "product.price7">{{product.baby}}</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <ngb-rating [(rate)]="product.averageRating" [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="true" max="5"></ngb-rating>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        
        <hr>
        <p class="lead">{{ product.description }}</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="lead">{{ product.specs}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 father">
        <div class="card bg-light">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Price:  ₦ {{ product.price}}  <del class=" price-old">{{product.oldprice}}</del> </h5>
```

and my ts code is

```
  priceChange1(event) {
            let product: any;
        if (event.priceChange1){
        product.price2 === product.price
      }
  }

  public priceChange2(event) {
    {
    product.price1 === product.price
  
}

  priceChange3(event) {
     product.price === product.price3
    
  }

  priceChange4(event: any) {
  
     product.price === product.price4
    
  }

  priceChange5($event) {
      product.price5 === product.price
    
  }

  priceChange6($event) {
   
      product.price6 === product.price
    
  }

  priceChange7($event) {
    
      product.price7 === product.price
    
  }
```

Please i would like the product price to change to the variation price when i click each variation button.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you narrow your question down? What exactly are you having trouble with? 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Each button has a price attached to it , i would like to set each button price as the main price when i click each button